# How to create an instrument

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio

I'm working on [LoadPresetDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Listings/LoadPresetDemo_Classes_MainViewController_m.html). The Trombone is made of 3 CAF files.
How can I create my own instrument, just like the Trombone?

Comment: Ok, found it on my own. This is how it goes: You Have to Download Audio Tools for xCode [link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-). There you'll find AU Lab, with which you can create your own instrument.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the docs for that [LoadPresetDemo example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) before posting your question?

From the Read Me:

> To learn how the preset files used in this sample code project were
>
> created using AU Lab in Mac OS X, view the Music in iOS and Lion
>
> presentation from WWDC 2011, and in particular the section on the Sampler
>
> audio unit. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=411